# Formula for getting a single 0-based index from two 0-based for loop iterators?

Tags: javascript, loops, math, iteration, formulas

This has got to be a thing. If I have something like this in Javascript

```
var c = 0;
var arr = [
  [a,b,c,d],
  [e,f,g],
  [h,i,j,k,l]
];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){

  }
}
```

How do I get a single 0-based index based off of i and j?
To be clear, after every iteration of the inner j loop c should increment to the next number in 0 - 11.

Comment: what is `a ... l`?

Comment: *after every iteration of the inner j loop c should increment to the next number in 0 - 11.*, so...`c++;` then?

Comment: If the question is how to calculate `c` directly for any given `i` and `j` then because your inner arrays don't have the same length you will have to loop the outer array and add up the lengths from `0...i` and then add `j`.

Comment: HA wow wowowow yeah. yeeeah that'll do it. For whatever reason my brain reeeeally wanted to have a function or something that took i and j and gave me c.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
var arr = [
  ['a','b','c','d'],
  ['e','f','g'],
  ['h','i','j','k','l']
];
var output = [];

arr.forEach(function(item){
  output.concat(item);
});
```

Output:

```
  ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 'h','i','j','k','l']
```